# Streamreader causing while loop to stop

Tags: loops, while-loop, tcpclient, streamreader, steam

I am trying to use a streamreader to catch strings that are send via a TCPClient however instead of constantly pooling, it will only go through the loop one.

```
private void recMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String listAsString = "";
            try
            {
                listAsString = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Interaction.MsgBox("Lost connection with server./n/n" + e);
                break;
            }


            newSprite(listAsString);

            }
        }
     }
```

It seems to pause at
        listAsString = streamReader.ReadLine();

Any Ideas?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1):

`ReadLine` blocks until enough data has arrived or the stream has ended. Make your code deal with that fact. Probably, you should move blocking IO to the background thread. Or better yet, use `await`.